# Subtracting values from two lists and adding the differences in R

Tags: r, loops

Let's say I have one  `num[1:25]` with values `3, 4, 5, 6 ...`
and another list with values `num[1:25] 5, 7, 4 ...`

I want to subtract values and add these differences together such that:

`(3-5) + (4-7) + (5-4)...`

so the first number in the first list with the first number in the other list and so on.

Comment: You can just do `sum(v1 - v2)` where `v1` is the first vector and `v2` the second one

Comment: ... and in your case that would of course be the same as sum(v1) - sum(v2) -- just in case the two vectors do not always have the same length.

Comment: akrun, I was just looking at the results from the sum(v1 - v2) with different length vectors. Will R simply recycle the shorter vector starting from the first element to complete the subtraction for each element in the longer one?

Comment: It will recycle, but it may also throw a warning message if the length is not a multiple of the shorter

Answer (score 0):

If your vectors are saved in the same list `lst`, you can try the code below

```
> sum(do.call("-", lst))
[1] -24
```

or

```
> diff(sapply(rev(lst), sum))
[1] -24
```

**Dummy Data**

```
set.seed(1)
lst <- list(
  sample(10, 25, replace = TRUE),
  sample(10, 25, replace = TRUE)
)
```